# why the Placeholderdo not work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

when i onblur on the input which type is "password",it will hide the placeholder thing and the input.

[plugin github link](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder)

Comment: you should put way more information here. Following the link you provided I found this: https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder/issues/20 . Could be the same issue...I don't know. If it's not please add more information and an example.

Comment: You didn't give anything but a link to a plugin. So ask him!!! (by the way it works with IE6+...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok,we take the the  [jquery.placeholder.js](https://github.com/danielstocks/jQuery-Placeholder/blob/master/jquery.placeholder.js)

and we can see the line 57

```
        // IE < 9 doesn't allow changing the type of password inputs
        if ($.browser.msie && input[0].outerHTML) {
            var fakeHTML = $(input[0].outerHTML.replace(/type=(['"])?password\1/gi, 'type=$1text$1'));
            this.fakePassword = fakeHTML.val(input.attr('placeholder')).addClass('placeholder').focus(function() {
                input.trigger('focus');
                $(this).hide();
                input.show();    //add this code
            });
            $(input[0].form).submit(function() {
                fakeHTML.remove();
                input.show()
            });
        }
```

add the code "input.show();" ,you can make the input not hide in IE8.